# Open 3rd party Android App from html

Tags: android, html

I have been researching how to open an app via a local HTML page.

Everything I have found seams to assume that I own/wrote the app and is suggesting using the apps "intent" to open it. However, I need to be able to open specific 3rd party apps for local use such as google home to which I don't know the apps intent and using market:// doesnt actually open the app, just takes you to the google play page for the app.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: you can't just open any app from HTML. The app should be listening for the "open URI" events for the specific pattern. For example, facebook is listening to `https://facebook.com/...` links. So the app you want to open should support it.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of... Thanks for your help Vlad